# Get data with am pm in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to generate query with some text(am pm with time based) in mysql.

My table like this

```
id   starttime    endtime
1    9:00         10:00
2    14:00        16:00
```

My time is in 24 hrs format. I want query with result.

```
id   starttime     endtime
1    9:00am        10:00am
2    2:00pm        4:00pm
```

How to do it?

Comment: Read about [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). By the way, there is no 14:00pm or 16:00pm.

Comment: i guess that is a typo. it needs to be `2:00pm` and `4:00pm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

```
SELECT id,
        DATE_FORMAT(starttime, '%h:%i %p') AS starttime,
        DATE_FORMAT(endtime, '%h:%i %p') AS endtime
FROM TableName
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f602d/1).

However, if your column's datatype is string. You need to convert it to `DATETIME` or `TIME` using `STR_TO_DATE` in order for `DATE_FORMAT()` to fucntion properly.

```
SELECT id,
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(starttime, '%k:%i'), '%h:%i %p') AS starttime,
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(endtime, '%k:%i'), '%h:%i %p') AS endtime
FROM TableName;
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e9f3/2).

Comment: it is working fine but ,if time is not there then it  takes 12:00Am by default how it was empty@John Woo

Comment: @Nadh, according to this demo,if there is no value then it will return null - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf8e01/1

Answer (score 1):

We can use `TIME_FORMAT` as below

```
mysql> select TIME_FORMAT('14:00', '%r') ;
+----------------------------+
| TIME_FORMAT('14:00', '%r') |
+----------------------------+
| 02:00:00 PM                |
+----------------------------+
```

or if its from a table **tablename** and columns are **starttime and endtime**, then,

```
select id,TIME_FORMAT(starttime, '%r'),TIME_FORMAT(endtime, '%r') from tablename;
```

or we can use `DATE_FORMAT` as below, (note: if `starttime` and `endtime` are `time` data type)

```
select id,DATE_FORMAT(starttime, '%h:%i %p'),DATE_FORMAT(endtime, '%h:%i %p') from tablename;
```

I hope this will do your work,